# C++: custom deleter status

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I declare a type like

```
template <typename T>
using SmartPtr = std::unique_ptr<T, MyDeleter>;
```

In some specific cases, i wanted to count references to an object and conditionally delete it when the pointer will be out of scope.

I know there is std::shared_ptr class but I have some objects I want to access through a common interface. Some of those objects are owned by their class, other classes have a factory method that yield the ownership of the objects they create.

My questions are:

- Does every pointer of type `SmartPtr` have an own, personal `MyDeleter` object?
- Is having multiple `std::unique_ptr`s pointing to the same object considered a bad coding practice? Even though I use a custom deleter?

It feels wrong to me to use shared_ptr without a deleter because the objects owned by class can't be anyway deleted because they wasn't created through new. They are part of an array, member of the class. Not all the objects pointed by SmartPtr was created using new operator.

Comment: _"Is having multiple std::unique_ptrs pointing to the same object"_ The word "unique" is a giveaway, isn't it? Can you explain further why `std::shared_ptr` won't work for you?

Comment: Because some object aren't shared and can't be. I need the move semantics for them. Others can be shared. I want to access all these objects through a common pointer type.

Comment: That seems pretty ludicrous to me. Why do you think you need this?

Comment: I try to explain:
I have a mathematical expression tree with nodes of type OpNode
This class have a member that is a pointer to an object of one of these types: BinaryOperator, UnaryOperator, Integral, Derivative, Limit...

The first 2 classes own the object they create (because they can be shared). The others yield the ownership of their objects (because they have a status, for example a variable to calculate the limit...)

When OpNode goes out of scope it must delete it's pointed object only if it had the ownership of that object.

Comment: Why not use boost spirit? Then it's a question of finding a use for all the spare time you'll have. Drop this funny pointer idea, and move on.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit rolling an intrusive smart counting pointer using a unique_ptr with a custom deleter isn't an unusable design.  It does needlessly block copy construct, and it gives a type name that is misleading.  Myself, I'd instead write my own intrusive smart counting pointer, but it would own a unique_ptr instead of a raw pointer inside of it.  That unique_ptr would decrement the use count, so would basically be what OP is thinking of doing: I just would cloak it in a layer, so I get copy operations and a better name.

Comment: Why not just write a PointerType trait that defaults to `unique_ptr`, and specialize it to `shared_ptr` for the types that need it? It seems much, much simpler.

Comment: @biowep: `shared_ptr` gives you move semantics.  The reference count goes from 1 to 2 back to 1 without ever copying the target.

Comment: @BenVoigt It feels wrong to me to use shared_ptr without a deleter because the objects owned by class can't be anyway deleted because they wasn't created through new. They are part of an array, member of the class.

Comment: I mean, not all the objects pointed by SmartPtr was created using new operator.

Comment: How is the lifetime of the class containing the data managed?  Are you writing expression templates?

Comment: @Yakk the lifetime is the whole execution time. No, I'm not

Comment: @biowep It sometimes points at things it owns and sometimes it doesn't?  I've seen this before, has an easy solution.  `std::unqiue_ptr<T>` and `T*` members both.  `T*` always points at the data, `std::unique_ptr<T>` also points to the same data if it owns the object, otherwise it's NULL.  Simple.

Comment: @MooingDuck Yes, but I don't have a common type pointer to access both owned and not owned data.

Comment: @biowep: Sure you do: The `T*` always points to the data, owned or unowned.  The `unique_ptr` is only there to manage the lifetime. The only time you need to touch the `unique_ptr` is for construction.

Comment: @MooingDuck Now I understand, I always use the raw pointer. `unique_ptr` is just to auto delete the object. Interesting, I will think about this solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to have a pointer member that may or may not own the thing it points at?  Easy, seperation of concerns:

```
std::unique_ptr<T> maybe_owning;
T* always_pointing;

constructor(const T& copy_and_own)
    :maybe_owning( new T(copy_and_own))
    ,always_pointing(maybe_owning.get())
{}
constructor(T* just_reference)
    :maybe_owning()
    ,always_pointing(just_reference)
{}
void do_task() {
   always_pointing->thing();
}
```

You have a single pointer that always points to the data, and doesn't care about ownership in the slightest.
You also have a smart pointer that can conditionally be used to own.
All problems solved, with no crazy code.

I use this commonly actually, an `fstream` that may or may not open a file, and a `istream&` which sometimes connects to the `fstream` and sometimes to `cin`, then I can read from either source the same.

Answer (score 2):

This is a working "maybe deletes, maybe not" class:

```
enum class should_delete {
  yes,
  no,
};
struct maybe_delete {
  should_delete choice = should_delete::yes;
  template<class T>
  void operator()(T* t){
    if (choice!=should_delete::no)
      delete t;
  }
  maybe_delete() = default;
  maybe_delete(should_delete c):choice(c) {}
  maybe_delete(maybe_delete const&)=default;
  // move in terms of copy, then clear state to default:
  maybe_delete(maybe_delete&& o):maybe_delete(o){
    o.choice = should_delete::yes;
  }
};
template<class T>
using maybe_unique_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T, maybe_delete>;
```

is a type that might be a unique pointer.

[live exmaple](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/757ade582c30573d)

Construct with `{ptr, should_delete::no}` in order to have the pointer not delete the object in question.  (moved) copies of such a `maybe_unique_ptr` will have the proper state.

Note that `.reset(ptr)` can be dangerous, because the object gets the deletion state of what was there before.  I ensured that moved-from `maybe_unique_ptr`s have the same state as trivially constructed ones with the careful `maybe_delete` move ctor.

---

That being said, if you want to write an intrusive smart pointer, I wouldn't do it as a raw `unique_ptr`.

If you look at `std::shared_ptr`, they have the "god mode" constructor:

```
shared_ptr<T>::shared_ptr( T*, shared_ptr<U> )
```

which lets you have a shared-ptr to `T` that forwards all reference counting to a completely different shared-ptr.  This is intended for "member" shared-ptrs (among other uses) -- if you have a structure `X` with a member `Y`, you can have a shared-ptr-to `Y` that actually reference counts the enclosing `X` structure.

For an intrusive smart pointer, I'd write a smart pointer.  It would store a `T*` and a "scope guard" type object for cleanup that does the decrement (the scope guard could even be a `unique_ptr` to a reference counting interface with a destroyer that decrements).  Do the boilerplate for a smart pointer (a few dozen lines).  On copy, clone the scope guard and the `T*`.  On move, move the pointer and scope guard (and clear the source).

Have constructors that wrap a raw `T*` with a null `ref_count` (if needed), or a `T*` and a `ref_count` interface, or both-as-one.

If the containing objects have a ref count, I'd be tempted to use that, just to early detect shutdown issues.

---

[bonus version with arbitrary deleter guarded by `maybe_delete`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/615de0ee9bd0742f).  That would allow you to refcount decrement conditionally, for example, without mixing the two operations too much.  Uses empty base class optimization to prevent wasted space (as `std::default_delete` is empty).